# db.trasaction doesnt wait for callback. Intel Xdk

Tags: android, sqlite, web-sql, intel-xdk

I was working on creating mobile app with web sql as database. I am trying to return array from one function as below

```
getCheckedItems:function(type,itemId){
                var optArr=[];
                var sql ="select optionid as opt from MyTable where familymemberid=" + this.memberId+ " and questionid="+itemId
                    MyDb.runQuery(sql, function(optionrecords) {
                        if(optionrecords.length>0)
                        {
                            if(type==2)
                            {
                              var optionId=optionrecords[0].opt;
                              optArr.push(optionId);
                                alert(optArr);
                              //  alert(optionId+"Hello");
                            }

                            else
                            {
                              for(var i=0;i<optionrecords.length;i++)
                              {
                              optArr.push(optionrecords[i].opt);
                              } 
                            }
                        }

                        }); 
       alert(optArr);
        return optArr;
    }
```

But here Second alert i.e `optArr` is shown before alert in transaction. How can I make wait  db transaction to be completed before array is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no web sql expert, but my guess is you're missing a `;` at the end of the `var sql = ...` line and that might be causing some unexpected behavior.